# Asp.Net Core Automapper LINQ expression

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm currently working with ASP.NET Core and I want to use Automapper to map a Linq Expression. The mapping statement is:

```
var targetConditions = _mapper.Map<Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>>(filter);
```

where **filter** is a formal parameter in the form:

```
(Expression<Func<EntityDTO, bool>> filter
```

In the mapping profile I have the following map created:

```
CreateMap<Expression<Func<EntityDTO, bool>>, Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>>();
```

I'm using a generic repository pattern with EF. I want to get a list of DTOs filtered by, of course, DTO's fields from my controller. I then need to convert from DTO filter to entities filter in the Business Layer before doing any query using Linq for EF.

Even though the expression does get coverted from EntityDTO to Entity, the parameters in the lambda expressions inside don't, raising all sorts of errors when I further use it with EF. Any idea how can this be done?

Comment: Did you have a map for `CreateMap<EntityDTO, Entity>();`?

Comment: @Win. Yes, I do have it

Comment: How do you use it? Could you create [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
IQueryable<Customer> query = repository.getCustomers(); // entities query
query.ProjectTo<CustomerDto>().Where(dtoFilterExpression)
```

Comment: That needs automapper ef extensions.

Comment: That needs IQueryableExtensions and works with any IQueryable, including entity framework ones. What's a problem here?

Comment: Thanks @YaserMoradi. That was it! I saw that solution before but I couldn't make it work for some reason. Thanks again!